# Redirects in in embeds tags don't redirect the normal page

Tags: embed

In an embed I have a redirect. The location of the embed gets changed rather than the location of the actual page. How should I fix it?

The website that I am having troubles on is www.willmargulies.com if you click on anything in the headbar

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Can you help me tho? lol